# How can I Get Company Name from customer Billing Address in Customer information tab in Admin?

Tags: customer, customer-address

I am trying to get Company Name to display in Magento admin but I can't get the value for just the Company name and nothing else.

Here is my code

```
<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getAddress()->getCompany()) ?>
```

Can anyone let me know what I've done wrong here?

Comment: Please add some details: In which function/class are you trying to echo the value => which class/super class is $this of? What does "cant't get the value" mean: error, empty value? Try to var_dump the value and see what is returned.

Comment: Hi, I am inside `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_View` and need to echo the value inside `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/view.phtml` and the moment I am not getting the value for company using the code above...

Comment: Should be $this->getCustomer()->getBillingAddress()->getCompany() then i guess (or getShippingAddress()). Did not try it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the company name inside `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/view.phtml` by using the following code:

Getting the company name from the billing address:

```
<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCustomer()->getBillingAddress()->getCompany()); ?>
```

Getting the company name from the shipping address:

```
<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCustomer()->getShippingAddress()->getCompany()); ?>
```